# Helidon @scheduled concurrentExecution property working not clear

Tags: helidon

how does the concurrentexecution property of the @scheduled annotaion behave in 3.2.1.

i have fixed rate that run every 20 seconds, and each run does nothing but sleep for 25 seconds.

I have tried both the ways of setting concurrentexecution to true and false, in either case the next run triggers irrespective of the current run has finished or not.

here is the code

`private  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);`

`@Scheduled(value= "0/20 * * * * ?", concurrentExecution = false)`

`public void stuckThreadShooter() {`

`System.out.println("Starting fixed rate execution at" + new  Date().toString());`

`for( int i=0; i<1 ; i++) {`

`executorService.execute(()->{`

`System.out.println("Starting run for thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " "+ new Date().toString());`

`run();`

`});`

`}}`

```
private static void run(){
 try {
    Thread.sleep(25000);
    System.out.println("Completed run for thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " "+ new  Date().toString());
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Output:
Starting fixed rate execution atTue Jun 13 15:54:20 IST 2023
Starting run for thread: pool-4-thread-1 Tue Jun 13 15:54:20 IST 2023
Starting fixed rate execution atTue Jun 13 15:54:40 IST 2023
Completed run for thread: pool-4-thread-1 Tue Jun 13 15:54:45 IST 2023

Answer (score 0):

You have to declaratively delegate all the scheduling work and not engage your own thread or thread pool. By spawning your own thread within the scheduled method, you are hiding the fact that you have a 25-second task from the scheduler since the scheduled method would return immediately. Perform the 25-second task in the called thread itself.

Below is your code fixed to remove manual thread management.

```
@Scheduled(value= "0/20 * * * * ?", concurrentExecution = false)
//@FixedRate(initialDelay = 0, value = 20, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void stuckThreadShooter() 
{
  System.out.println("Starting fixed rate execution at" + new Date().toString());

  try 
  {
    Thread.sleep(25000);
  } 
  catch (InterruptedException e) 
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("Completed run for thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " "+ new  Date().toString());
}
```